# How to enable date input and re format it ready for mysqli insert or select

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am wanting to allow the date input in a html form to be

UK Format - DD/MM/YYYY , when submitted, before any php code is executed in the sense of queries... e.g. select, insert etc etc...

I want php to change the date inputted  **DD/MM/YYYY** to **YYYY-MM-DD**

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-mb-3">
    <label for="betDate"> Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Date" id="Date" placeholder="Date" value="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-mb-3">
    <label for="sport">Sport</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sport" id="sport" placeholder="sport" >
  </div>
```

Comment: Is there anything you've already tried on php side?

Comment: @kuh-chan I know how to do the mysqli insert etc... I just don't know how to change the format of the date entered before I want to do mysqli queries with e.g.  _POST data

Answer (score 2):

Use type "date" in your input, you can also limit a range of the date allowed to be set.

```
<input type="date" min="2019-02-01" max="2019-02-02">
```

You will see a format of the country where is watching the website, for example London, and when send form, will transform it (always) to database format (yyyy-mm-dd) when you get with php.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it always changed it when going to database, 

is the the same for when you do SELECT? will it transform it and look in the database as YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: The DATE columns in MYSQL have YYYY-MM-DD in default.When you select a date you will get YYYY-MM-DD, but you can also transform with DATE functions in MYSQL or PHP (search it in google)

Comment: Edited, you can understand better now!